# Transfer grandchildren to become children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements all of the `.dataCard` class divided into a left and right column, which are children of the main container. So the `.dataCard` elements are grandchildren of `#main`.

I'm trying to go from the left column to the right column and take the first child from each column and transfer it into `#main` then remove it from the column it came from; thus, making it a child of `#main` and not a grandchild.

Here is what I have tried, but when I run it, I get an empty `#main':

```
$('.dataCard').each(function(){
    $('#main').append($('#left').first());
    $('#left').first().remove();
    $('#main').append($('#right').first());
    $('#right').first().remove();
});
```

I've also tried this, but I understand why this also causes an empty `#main` because it clears the `#main` when it writes the html of `#main` because then there is nothing to reference as now the `#left` and `#right` are gone.

```
$('.dataCard').each(function(){
    $('#main').html($('#left').first());
    $('#left').first().remove();
    $('#main').html($('#right').first());
    $('#right').first().remove();
});
```

How can I transfer the `.dataCard` elements in the order, one from the left column, one from the right column, into `#main`?

Edit:

My markup:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="dataCard" data-cardNumber="1">...</div>
        <div class="dataCard" data-cardNumber="3">...</div>
        <div class="dataCard" data-cardNumber="5">...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="dataCard" data-cardNumber="2">...</div>
        <div class="dataCard" data-cardNumber="4">...</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @TusharGupta Updated my question with my markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/tus7V/)</kbd>

```
var x = $('#main .dataCard').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('cardnumber') - $(b).data('cardnumber');//sort according to data-cardNumber attribute
}).appendTo('#main', function () { //append to div with id main
    $('#left,#right').remove();//remove div with id left and right
});
```

---

[.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

---

To [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) first child to div with id main

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/tus7V/2)</kbd>

```
$('#main').append($('#left').find('.dataCard').first());
$('#main').append($('#right').find('.dataCard').first());
```

or [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/tus7V/1)</kbd>

```
$('#main').prepend($('#left').find('.dataCard').first());
$('#main').prepend($('#right').find('.dataCard').first());
```

Comment: I was interested in this demo, but the output doesn't seem to be sorted in the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/tus7V/

Comment: the proper output should be 1,2,3,4,5 in sorted order.

Comment: I am now encountering another issue with `.html()` not writing properly. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could take a look. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20302498/2829610