# Trying to write HTML in variable using .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write HTML stored in a variable to the main container, but when I write it, the main container ends up empty.

I console.logged the variable and it contains the html, but when I pass it as the argument / parametre of the `.html()` function on the next line, when the code is ran, the html of the selector is empty and not that html in the variable.

Here is what one needs to do to recreate the problem:

1. Visit this page: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcTkxWSkpxRXFQU2c/KE_home.html
2. Drag away one of the cards to the left or to the right
3. Within 6 seconds, click the undo button or text in the notification at the top
4. Witness the main container's html become empty

What I'm trying to do is revert back to the html before the card was swiped away; thus, simulating an undo.

Here it a snippet of the jQuery / javascript that creates the notification

```
$.createNotification({
    horizontal: 'center', // horizontally centre notification
    vertical: 'top', // top align notification
    content: 'Card Dismissed.<span style="cursor:pointer; margin-left:32px;">Undo ↩</span>', // content of notification
    duration: 6000, // 6 seconds notification lasts
    click: function () { // what to do on notification once it is clicked
        $('#main').html(mainHTML); // write the html, here is where #main becomes empty
        console.log(mainHTML); // but this console.log shows that mainHTML has the right HTML in the variable
        console.log("break-time! #4"); // random debugging line
        var a = $('.lastCardDragged').attr('data-cardNumber'); // removes rewritten card from an array of cards that have been swiped away
        for (var b = 0, c = swipedAwayCards.length; b < c; b++) {
            if (swipedAwayCards[b] == a) {
                swipedAwayCards.splice(b, 1);
                break;
            }
        };
        /* More code that sorts the cards and write the layouts into one or two columns */
        this.hide(); // hide notification
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we see a) how you create `mainHTML` and b) how/where you invoke $.createNotification?

Comment: `$('#left, #right').html("");` this is the code that causes it as also indicated by Pointy.

Comment: @JamesLai mainHTML is created by `var mainHTML = $('#main').html();' on the start of the drag of one of the cards. and that is how createNotification is invoked, just like that.

Comment: @melc What line number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That statement that assigns the saved markup *does* work. However, a little farther on, your code detects that the window is wider than some threshold, and it empties out the "left" and "right" containers inside the "main" element.